# Is there a way to links tasks that have overlapped dates?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

for example, if I have two tasks start at different dates that end at the same date.

[image]

My problem is, if I try to link these two tasks, the dates will automatically change, not the original dates I want to keep.

[image]

Is there a way to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Link the tasks as Finish-to-Finish instead of the default Finish-to-Start. Change the Predecessor field to say 2FF.